# Delete Subsets in Lists

Tags: python, list, subset

I have a list of list indices. I need to find a way to delete subsets that could occur within a list.

```
[44, 45, 54, 80, 103, 122, 125, 175, 176, 180, 210, 213]
[44, 54, 77, 80, 103, 122, 125, 171, 175, 176, 180, 210, 213]
[55, 87, 102, 119, 127, 132, 153, 166, 187, 197]
```

Clearly the first 2 lists share common indices, I need to combine these lists that share a large majority of common indices. I need the out put as follows.

```
[44, 45, 54, 77, 80, 103, 122, 125, 171, 175, 176, 180, 210, 213]
[55, 87, 102, 119, 127, 132, 153, 166, 187, 197]
```

Comment: Combining lists is quite easy: `new_list = list_a + list_b`. If you're thinking "no, I want to combine them in a way that's more sophisticated than just concatenation", please give more detail. What kind of output are you expecting to get from this input?

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question. Do you want a list of all the common  number in a list of lists?

Comment: Using set operations: `common = set(list_a) & set(list_b)`?

Comment: For the three lists you have provided, please could you [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44029326/edit) to show what your expected output would be.

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean by "large majority of common indices". Do you really mean something like "more than 50% of the elements in common"?

Comment: It seems you don't mean "subset" because lists 1 and 2 have unique elements (e.g. 45 and 77).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for `set.union`:

```
>>> s = set([44, 45, 54, 80, 103, 122, 125, 175, 176, 180, 210, 213])
>>> s2 = set([44, 54, 77, 80, 103, 122, 125, 171, 175, 176, 180, 210, 213])
>>> s.union(s2)
set([77, 80, 210, 213, 103, 171, 44, 45, 175, 176, 180, 54, 122, 125])
>>> sorted(list(s.union(s2)))
[44, 45, 54, 77, 80, 103, 122, 125, 171, 175, 176, 180, 210, 213]
```

Comment: I have a list of lists, so I don't know  which lists are subsets